# Unable to update util-linux

Tags: apt, dpkg

```
sudo apt-get install util-linux 

 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm3.8
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
Suggested packages:
  util-linux-locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  util-linux
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
Checking index: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages)(Trusted=1)
Need to get 0 B/849 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 211924 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) over (2.27.1-6ubuntu3) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './sbin/ctrlaltdel' to '/sbin/ctrlaltdel.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
insserv: warning: script 'wildfly' missing LSB tags and overrides
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `lzma error: compressed data is corrupt`.  Delete the corrupt package from your local cache, then try again.

Comment: `insserv: warning: script 'wildfly' missing LSB tags and overrides`.  Fix your /etc/init.d/wildfly script header while you in a fixing mood.  But that's a different question (search, been answered several times)

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt update -f`, then upgrade with `apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>`

Comment: Tried same still same error.
RCA is :
cannot copy extracted data for './sbin/ctrlaltdel' to '/sbin/ctrlaltdel.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream

Comment: I have cleared cache now I am getting hash sum mismatch
 
ReceivedHash:
 - SHA256:f70a2b41bbcb5a8a292c083b2f46b7de11cc10566a3dd9127c3891466a9258f3
 - SHA1:4a06a530a7ebf876b4cc7c246dc67ba1ac931562
 - MD5Sum:cc6cab2f45783f0da55c29bdb2cbc6c9
 - Checksum-FileSize:848570
ExpectedHash:
 - SHA256:6534386fed6f45df06ae9f7b9e56edaac66bbaa7ba861283778ad7adc1b52f2f
 - SHA1:055c72c2f7a24f7d6c38a2ff9d06b844b1c7a219
 - MD5Sum:11977894d851c39f39c3c9b1d5fc3028
 - Checksum-FileSize:848570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by using this link

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/